# Select matching words in the editable area

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tags, contenteditable

There is array with words. `const = ['cat','dog']`. Also textarea or input,  or editable div. I need to write words in this field and highlight words if they match.
Now I have a bad variant because I use the highlight npm package and contain it over the input field and hide input text. Caret runs ahead and also I have a lot of problems besides all this.
The default value from this form goes to useState.
Also, I should be able to call the onKeyPress function or something similar, because I add a new tag if `e.keyCode === 32` and contain #.

I need to do it use react function component. [image: This is the perfect option, but only in the picture]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this(code mentioned below)?
Also, I didn't understand the part of using a key, what do you exactly want to achieve with it.
And keyCode is deprecated, I'll suggest you use key `key==='#'`
Plus, if you can add a code snippet or elaborate more would help in helping you better

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
const Input = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const tagsArr = useMemo(() => ({ cats: false, dogs: false }), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    Object.keys(tagsArr).forEach((el, i) => {
      if (inputValue.includes(el)) {
        tagsArr[el] = true;
      } else {
        tagsArr[el] = false;
      }
    });
  }, [inputValue, tagsArr]);
  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    setInputValue(target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      <div>
        <ul>
          {Object.keys(tagsArr).map((el, i) =>
            tagsArr[el] ? (
              <li
                key={el}
                style={{
                  listStyle: "none",
                  backgroundColor: "springgreen",
                  width: "max-content",
                  display: "inline",
                  padding: "10px",
                  marginRight: "10px",
                }}
              >
                {"#" + el}
                <button>X</button>
              </li>
            ) : null
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Input;
```

Comment: I need to add a word to the tag below at the end of the input (by pressing the space bar) and if the word contains a #.

Comment: @SergeyKyharyonok I still didn't get it. Add a word to which tag below at the end of the input?
Did you check the solution, does it match anywhere near to your needs?

Comment: For example: the user enters the text “I wanna go to #shop". As the input is completed, the corresponding tag should be created and displayed in the list below the text field.
When editing a note, all words that match the tags should be highlighted.

Comment: The tags should be created after the user makes submit call or on every input change

Comment: if you open Edit Mode and write #tag and press spacebar it's word should be add in hashtags block below and in input should be highlight yellow because it's word matches with tag below.